# What is the difference between JsonWriter and JsonTextWriter?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core

What is the difference between JsonWriter and JsonTextWriter?

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/WriteJsonWithJsonTextWriter.htm

```
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("CPU");
    writer.WriteValue("Intel");
```

shouldn't it been `JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw)` for consistency  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonWriter is an abstract base class. Defining a variable of this type is similar to using an interface; an abstract class and an interface both provide an abstract contract which define the minimum required members of the classes that implement them.

> shouldn't it been JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw) for
>   consistency

By defining the `writer` variable as a JsonWriter, the coder is signalling that they are not going to use any members unique to the implementation (JsonTextWriter). They only intend to use members that belong to the contract. This means any code that calls members on this `writer` (without casting it) will compile and should continue to work if you were to change the implementation to some other class derived from JsonWriter.

Answer (score 1):

As you would have seen from the documentation, [`JsonTextWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) is derived from [`JsonWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm)

> `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` are low-level classes and are primarily for
>   internal use by Json.NET. To quickly work with JSON, either the
>   serializer - Serializing and Deserializing JSON - or using LINQ to
>   JSON is recommended.

and

> `JsonTextReader` and `JsonTextWriter` are used to read and write JSON
>   text. The `JsonTextWriter` has a number of settings on it to control how
>   JSON is formatted when it is written. These options include
>   formatting, indentation character, indent count, and quote character.

As to the question

> shouldn't it been JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw) for
>   consistency

in this example it was sufficient just to use the initialised type as the base class as the demo didn't need any more functionality than was exposed in the base class

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't it be JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw) for consistency then ? just curious started learning about this

Comment: @Joe572Thomas updated, i would actually just use `using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw)) `

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but may be it is the reason for it.
The JsonTextWriter has a number of settings on it to control how JSON is formatted when it is written.
Represents a writer that provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only way of generating JSON data.

JsonTextWriter is sub class of jsonText class.
so at object create time we have to write like this

```
(JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
```